# Fatal Error in Php

Tags: php

I am getting the following error when i run a php code.
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in line 143".
What should i do. It goes into a for loop during this line

Comment: http://www.php.net/set_time_limit if your code is valid and just requires some more time to run. You can change this limit in php.ini

Comment: If the loop is intentional you can increase the max execution time with [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Show us some code. This isn't a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it is probably an infinite loop.

Make sure you are exiting the loop at some point. Probably the condition for continuing the loop is always true so it never stops running the code inside.

If the huge number of iterations is intentional, you have to increase the time limit.